# Unable to sort wp_query by date/time with multiple meta_key s

Tags: custom-post-types, events

**4th EDIT 11/17/2011**

I spoke too soon.  Now I have all the posts showing up but the total events does not seperate the events by day after I moved the endif; and endwhile;  I posted the modified code below and below this is the previously modified code.

Before the count was correct for each day.  If I had two events from different posts on Friday then it would say "2 Events on Friday"  but it would only display the content of the most recent post.

Now it displays the content of all the posts  but if I have two events from different posts on Friday then it say "1 Event Friday" before each post.

Here is the code and Thank you.

```
<?php
      $today = date("Y-m-d 00:00");  //set today's date 
      $todaytext = date("l"); // define $todaytext with written out days

  for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++){
      $thedate = strtotime ( '+'.$i.' day' , strtotime ( $today ) ) ;
      $thedate = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' , $thedate );
      $thedatetext = strtotime ( '+'.$i.' day' , strtotime ( $todaytext ) ) ;
      $thedatetext = date ( 'l' , $thedatetext );
      $future = strtotime ( '+24 hours' , strtotime ( $thedate ) ) ;
      $future = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' , $future ); 

 $args = array(
 'post_type' => 'event',
 'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
 'order'       => 'asc',
 'meta_query' => array(
 'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'opening_time',
        'value' => array($today,$future),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'artist_talk_time',
        'value' => array($today,$future),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'    
    )
)
);

$event_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

if ($event_query->have_posts()) : while ($event_query->have_posts()) :  $event_query->the_post();    

$keys = array('opening_time', 'film_time', 'artist_talk_time');
$times = array();  // I tried putting the new array line here but then I got a repeat of the post for everyday
$custom_field_keys = get_post_custom_keys();
foreach ($custom_field_keys as $custom_field_key) {

if (in_array($custom_field_key, $keys)) 
{
    $custom_field_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field_key, true);

    if ($custom_field_value >= $thedate && $custom_field_value <= $future) {

        $counttest++;
        $times[] = array($custom_field_value, $post->ID, $custom_field_key); // I changed the array here

    }
    }
    }     


 if ($counttest >0) {
  echo $counttest;

  if ($counttest>=2){
  echo ' Events ';
  } // end if ($totalevents>=2) function

  if ($counttest<2){ 
  echo ' Event ';
  }
  echo $count;
  if ($thedate==$today){echo 'Today';}
  if ($thedate>$today){
  echo $thedatetext;}
  echo  '<br>';

  }

  $counttest=0;


  asort($times); // I changed the asort to sort here
  foreach ($times as $event) { $time_value = $event[0]; $post_id = $event[1]; $time_key = $event[2];  // changed the foreach here

if ($time_key == 'opening_time') { ?>

<li class="sidebar_event">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'upcoming_event_sidebar'); ?></a> 

<h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a></h2> 
<h3>Opening</h3>
<h4><?php echo get_post_meta($post_id,'event_venue', true);?> </h4>
<h5><?php echo get_post_meta($post_id,'opening_time', true);?> </h5>
</li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->
<?php }

else if ($time_key == 'artist_talk_time') { ?>

<li class="sidebar_event">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'upcoming_event_sidebar'); ?></a> 

<h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a></h2> 
<h3>Artist Talk</h3>
<h4><?php echo get_post_meta($post_id,'event_venue', true);?> </h4>
<h5><?php echo get_post_meta($post_id,'artist_talk_time', true);?> </h5>
</li><!-- end .sidebar_event -->
<?php }

  else if ($time_key == 'film_time') {
        ?>
  <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>">
  <?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a></h2> 
  <h2>Film</h2>
  <?php
  echo get_post_meta($post_id,'film_time', true); echo get_the_content($post_id); 
 }

 }
     endwhile;
  endif;

  rewind_posts();

  }
  ?>
```

**End 4th EDIT**

**3rd EDIT 11/17/2011**
I made the changes that you suggested Marcochiesi but the behavior stays the same.  I tried making any other changes that  I could wrap my heard around but know luck.  What would you try next?  Thank you so much for your help.

**revised code**

```
  <?php
      $today = date("Y-m-d 00:00");  //set today's date 
      $todaytext = date("l"); // define $todaytext with written out days

  for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++){
      $thedate = strtotime ( '+'.$i.' day' , strtotime ( $today ) ) ;
      $thedate = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' , $thedate );
      $thedatetext = strtotime ( '+'.$i.' day' , strtotime ( $todaytext ) ) ;
      $thedatetext = date ( 'l' , $thedatetext );
      $future = strtotime ( '+24 hours' , strtotime ( $thedate ) ) ;
      $future = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' , $future ); 

 $args = array(
 'post_type' => 'event',
 'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
 'order'       => 'asc',
 'meta_query' => array(
 'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'opening_time',
        'value' => array($today,$future),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'artist_talk_time',
        'value' => array($today,$future),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'    
    )
)
);

$event_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

if ($event_query->have_posts()) : while ($event_query->have_posts()) :  $event_query->the_post();    

$keys = array('opening_time', 'film_time', 'artist_talk_time');
$times = array();  // I tried putting the new array line here but then I got a repeat of the post for everyday
$custom_field_keys = get_post_custom_keys();
foreach ($custom_field_keys as $custom_field_key) {

if (in_array($custom_field_key, $keys)) 
{
    $custom_field_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field_key, true);

    if ($custom_field_value >= $thedate && $custom_field_value <= $future) {

        $counttest++;
        $times[] = array($custom_field_value, $post->ID, $custom_field_key); // I changed the array here

    }
    }
    }     
 endwhile;

 if ($counttest >0) {
  echo $counttest;

  if ($counttest>=2){
  echo ' Events ';
  } // end if ($totalevents>=2) function

  if ($counttest<2){ 
  echo ' Event ';
  }
  echo $count;
  if ($thedate==$today){echo 'Today';}
  if ($thedate>$today){
  echo $thedatetext;}
  echo  '<br>';
  }

  endif;
  $counttest=0;


 sort($times); // I changed the asort to sort here
 foreach ($times as $event) { $time_value = $event[0]; $post_id = $event[1]; $time_key = $event[2];  // changed the foreach here

 if ($time_key == 'opening_time') {
    ?>
  <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>">
  <?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a></h2> 
  <h2>Opening</h2>
  <?php
  echo get_post_meta($post_id,'opening_time', true); echo get_the_content($post_id); 

  }
  else if ($time_key == 'artist_talk_time') {
        ?>
  <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>">
  <?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a></h2> 
  <h2>Artist Talk</h2>
  <?php
  echo get_post_meta($post_id,'artist_talk_time', true); echo get_the_content($post_id); 

 }
  else if ($time_key == 'film_time') {
        ?>
  <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>">
  <?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a></h2> 
  <h2>Film</h2>
  <?php
  echo get_post_meta($post_id,'film_time', true); echo get_the_content($post_id); 
 }

 }

  rewind_posts();

  }
  ?>
```

**end 3rd EDIT**

**2nd EDIT 11/16/2011**
Marcochiesi, thanky for the additional help.  Now I get the right count of events and they are sorted properly.  The problem is that only the most recent post shows any content.  If I add a new CPT event then it will show the its title and permalink but if I delete it it goes back to the next most recent post.

Do you know what the problem is?  Thank you again.  It is impossible without your help.

**2nd revised code**

```
  <?php
      $today = date("Y-m-d 00:00");  //set today's date 
      $todaytext = date("l"); // define $todaytext with written out days

  for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++){
      $thedate = strtotime ( '+'.$i.' day' , strtotime ( $today ) ) ;
      $thedate = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' , $thedate );
      $thedatetext = strtotime ( '+'.$i.' day' , strtotime ( $todaytext ) ) ;
      $thedatetext = date ( 'l' , $thedatetext );
      $future = strtotime ( '+24 hours' , strtotime ( $thedate ) ) ;
      $future = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' , $future ); 

 $args = array(
 'post_type' => 'event',
 'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
 'order'       => 'asc',
 'meta_query' => array(
 'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'opening_time',
        'value' => array($today,$future),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'artist_talk_time',
        'value' => array($today,$future),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'    
    )
)
);

$event_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

if ($event_query->have_posts()) : while ($event_query->have_posts()) :  $event_query->the_post();    

$keys = array('opening_time', 'film_time', 'artist_talk_time');
$times = array();
$custom_field_keys = get_post_custom_keys();
foreach ($custom_field_keys as $custom_field_key) {

if (in_array($custom_field_key, $keys)) 
{
    $custom_field_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field_key, true);

    if ($custom_field_value >= $thedate && $custom_field_value <= $future) {

        $counttest++;

        $times[$custom_field_key] = array($custom_field_value, $post->ID);
    }
    }
    }     
 endwhile;
 if ($counttest >0) {
  echo $counttest;

  if ($counttest>=2){
  echo ' Events ';
  } // end if ($totalevents>=2) function

  if ($counttest<2){ 
  echo ' Event ';
  }
  echo $count;
  if ($thedate==$today){echo 'Today';}
  if ($thedate>$today){
  echo $thedatetext;}
  echo  '<br>';
  }

  endif;
   $counttest=0;


 asort($times);
 foreach ($times as $time_key => $event) {
 $time_value = $event[0]; $post_id = $event[1]; 

 if ($time_key == 'opening_time') {
    ?>
  <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>">
  <?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a></h2> 
  <h2>Opening</h2>
  <?php
  echo get_post_meta($post_id,'opening_time', true); echo get_the_content($post_id); 

 }
 else if ($time_key == 'artist_talk_time') {
        ?>
  <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>">
  <?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a></h2> 
  <h2>Artist Talk</h2>
  <?php
  echo get_post_meta($post_id,'artist_talk_time', true); echo get_the_content($post_id); 

 }
  else if ($time_key == 'film_time') {
        ?>
  <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>">
  <?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a></h2> 
  <h2>Film</h2>
  <?php
  echo get_post_meta($post_id,'film_time', true); echo get_the_content($post_id); 
 }

 }

  rewind_posts();

  }
  ?>
```

**END 2nd EDIT**

**EDIT 11/15/2011**

After changing the code from  marcochiesi (thank you)  I was able to stream line my if statements and gain the ability to sort artist_talk_time in front of opening_time if that is what the meta_key said.

But now I have duplicate posts coming from multiple days in the sorting.  Each CPT can have 3 meta_keys that have a date & time value.

Currently I have 3 test CPTs.
1 has an opening_time at 2:00 today (it shows up first)  It also has an artist talk time on the next day at 2:00.  This also shows up but in both today and tomorrow.

This behavior happens with all the posts.  What am I doing wrong?

**revised code**

```
 <?php
      $today = date("Y-m-d 00:00");  //set today's date 
      $todaytext = date("l");  // define $todaytext with written out days

 for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++){
      $thedate = strtotime ( '+'.$i.' day' , strtotime ( $today ) ) ;
      $thedate = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' , $thedate );
      $thedatetext = strtotime ( '+'.$i.' day' , strtotime ( $todaytext ) ) ;
      $thedatetext = date ( 'l' , $thedatetext );
      $future = strtotime ( '+23 hours' , strtotime ( $thedate ) ) ;
      $future = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' , $future ); 
 $args = array(
 'post_type' => 'event',
 'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
 'order'       => 'asc',
 'meta_query' => array(
 'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'opening_time',
        'value' => array($today,$future),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'artist_talk_time',
        'value' => array($today,$future),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'    
    )
)
);

$event_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

if ($event_query->have_posts()) : while ($event_query->have_posts()) :  $event_query->the_post();    

$keys = array('opening_time', 'film_time', 'artist_talk_time');
$times = array();
$custom_field_keys = get_post_custom_keys();

foreach ($custom_field_keys as $custom_field_key) {

if (in_array($custom_field_key, $keys)) 
{
    $custom_field_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field_key, true);

    if ($custom_field_value >= $thedate && $custom_field_value <= $future) {

        $counttest++;

        $times[$custom_field_key] = $custom_field_value;
    }
 }
 }     
 endwhile;
 if ($counttest >0) {
  echo $counttest;

  if ($counttest>=2){
  echo ' Events ';
  } // end if ($totalevents>=2) function

  if ($counttest<2){ 
  echo ' Event ';
  }
  echo $count;
  if ($thedate==$today){echo 'Today';}
  if ($thedate>$today){
  echo $thedatetext;}
  echo  '<br>';
  }

  endif;

  $counttest=0;

  if ($event_query->have_posts()) : while ($event_query->have_posts()) :  $event_query->the_post();

  asort($times);
  foreach ($times as $time_key => $time_value) {

  if ($time_key == 'opening_time') {
    ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title('<h2>', '</h2>'); ?></a>
  <h2>Opening</h2>

  <?php
  echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'opening_time', true);
  the_content();
  }
  else if ($time_key == 'artist_talk_time') {
        ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title('<h2>', '</h2>'); ?></a>
  <h2>Artist Talk</h2>

  <?php
  echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'artist_talk_time', true);
  the_content();
  }
  else if ($time_key == 'film_time') {
        ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title('<h2>', '</h2>'); ?></a>
  <h2>Artist Talk</h2>

  <?php
  echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'film_time', true);
  the_content();
  }

  }

  endwhile;

  endif;
  rewind_posts();

  }
  ?>
```

**END EDIT 11/15/2011 - Original Question Below**

Through help on this answers collection I have the code working below that sorts events by date and then lists them and counts them.  It does not filter by time.

For example, a single CPT 'event' has multiple meta_keys with a yyyy-mm-dd 00:00 entry.  Each main event or art opening runs for about a month, but there is also the opening reception and artist talks that have their own meta_keys opening_time and artist_talk_time.

I have another page that lists the month long portion of the events.  Now I am trying to list the upcoming events in order.

The problem is in an individual CPT "event" if the artist_talk_time is 16:00 and the opening_time is after 16:00, the opening_time shows first since it is called first in the loop where I display the_content().  This is not the behavior that I want.

All events on a single day, even if in the same CPT should be listed in order by time.

I am sure that I am doing this the wrong way and any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
<?php
      $today = date("Y-m-d 00:00");
      $todaytext = date("l");

  for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++){
      $thedate = strtotime ( '+'.$i.' day' , strtotime ( $today ) ) ;
      $thedate = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' , $thedate );
      $thedatetext = strtotime ( '+'.$i.' day' , strtotime ( $todaytext ) ) ;
      $thedatetext = date ( 'l' , $thedatetext );
      $future = strtotime ( '+23 hours' , strtotime ( $thedate ) ) ;
      $future = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i' , $future ); 
 $args = array(
 'post_type' => 'event',
 'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
 'order'       => 'asc',
 'meta_query' => array(
 'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'opening_time',
        'value' => array($today,$future),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'artist_talk_time',
        'value' => array($today,$future),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'    
    )
)
);

 $event_query = new WP_Query( $args );      

if ($event_query->have_posts()) : while ($event_query->have_posts()) :  $event_query->the_post(); 

if ((get_post_meta($post->ID,'opening_time', true)>=$thedate) && (get_post_meta($post->ID,'opening_time', true)<=$future))
  { $counttest++;}

if ((get_post_meta($post->ID,'film_time', true)>=$thedate) && (get_post_meta($post->ID,'_time', true)<=$future))
  { $counttest++;}

if ((get_post_meta($post->ID,'artist_talk_time', true)>=$thedate) && (get_post_meta($post->ID,'artist_talk_time', true)<=$future))
  { $counttest++;}

endwhile;
  if ($counttest >0) {
  echo $counttest;

  if ($counttest>=2){
  echo ' Events ';
  } // end if ($totalevents>=2) function

  if ($counttest<2){ 
  echo ' Event ';
  }
  echo $count;
  if ($thedate==$today){echo 'Today';}
  if ($thedate>$today){
  echo $thedatetext;}
  echo  '<br>';
  }

  endif;

  $counttest=0;

  if ($event_query->have_posts()) : while ($event_query->have_posts()) :  $event_query->the_post();

  if ((get_post_meta($post->ID,'opening_time', true)>=$thedate) && (get_post_meta($post->ID,'opening_time', true)<=$future))
  {
  ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title('<h2>', '</h2>'); ?></a>
  <h2>Opening Reception</h2>
  <?php
  echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'opening_time', true);
  the_content();

  }

  if ((get_post_meta($post->ID,'artist_talk_time', true)>=$thedate) && (get_post_meta($post->ID,'artist_talk_time', true)<=$future))
  { ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title('<h2>', '</h2>'); ?></a>
  <h2> Artist Talk </h2>
  <?php 
  echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'artist_talk_time', true);
  the_content();

  } 

  endwhile;

  endif;
  rewind_posts();

  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea: you could save your time values in an array and then sort it with PHP.
Example:

```
$keys = array('opening_time', 'film_time', 'artist_talk_time');
$times = array();
$custom_field_keys = get_post_custom_keys();
foreach ($custom_field_keys as $custom_field_key) {
    if (in_array($custom_field_key, $keys) {
        $custom_field_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field_key, true);
        if ($custom_field_value >= $thedate && $custom_field_value <= $future) {
            $counttest++;
            $times[$custom_field_key] = $custom_field_value;
        }
    }
}
asort($times);
foreach ($times as $time_key => $time_value) {
    if ($time_key == 'opening_time') {
        ...
    }
    else if ($time_key == 'film_time') {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: @marchochesi   Thank you.  Question: This would go after the first `if ($event_query->have_posts()) : while ($event_query->have_posts()) :  $event_query->the_post(); ` correct?

Then between ` if ($time_key == 'opening_time') {
        ...
    }`

I put `the_content();` correct?

Also I am getting a syntax error on the line ` if (in_array($custom_field_key, $keys) {
`
Since the data is in a meta box should I use `'meta_key'` instead of `'custom_key'`?
Will be trying every combination tonight.  Thank you again for the clarification.

Comment: Yes, the code goes inside the loop, after the first `if ($event_query->have_posts())...`. My code was a bit simplified, it was just an idea... I think you should save the post ids in an array too and then use a `get_the_content([post id])` in place of `the_content()`. The syntax error is caused by a missing `)` at the end of the `if`.

Comment: @marchochesi   I figured out the syntax issue. It was missing a ` C` and should read  ` if (in_array($custom_field_key, $keys)) ` Now I just have to figure out where the `if ($event_query->have_posts()) : while ($event_query->have_posts()) : $event_query->the_post(); ` goes.  Thank you again and I will keep working on it.  I must have been typing while you answered.

Comment: @marchochesi  Thank you again for your help.  I now have the posts sorting by time but the dates are messed up.  I am getting duplicate content in each day.  Is it something obvious?  Thank you for the advice.

Comment: I think you should avoid the second `while` loop (just use the `foreach`) and save the post ids for later use:
`$times[$custom_field_key] = array($custom_field_value, $post->ID);`
...
`foreach ($times as $time_key => $event) {`
`$time_value = $event[0];`
`$post_id = $event[1];`
...
`if ($time_key == 'opening_time') {`
`?>`
`<h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a></h2>`
...
`echo get_post_meta($post_id,'opening_time', true);`
`echo get_the_content($post_id);`
`}`

Comment: @marchochesi    Thank you.  That gets rid of the duplicate content.  The Event count is also accurate for each day.  Now the problem is that I only get content from the most recent post.  Other posts show up in the Event count but their content and titles do not appear.  Do you know what the issue is?  I put my new revised code up above.  I wish I understood more and thank you for the help as always.

Comment: Probably it's becauses the `$times` array gets overwritten. Try the following changes:
1. change array assigment: `$times[] = array($custom_field_value, $post->ID, $custom_field_key);`
2. change `asort` to `sort`
3. change the foreach: 
`foreach ($times as $event) {`
`$time_value = $event[0];`
`$post_id = $event[1];`
`$time_key = $event[2];`

Comment: @marchochesi     I tried the suggestions that you made but had no luck.  IT has the same behavior as before.  The most recent CPT is the only one that displays content.  I put comments in the revised code above to show where  I made the changes that you suggested.  Do you have any other suggestions?  Thank you so much for helping with something I just do not have the ability to do by myself.  Thank you.

Comment: @marchochesi    I played around with it a bit and put the `endwhile;` and `endif; down at the bottom just before the `rewind_posts();`  That seemed to solve the problem but I need to add a bunch more posts, test and see.  I will let you know.  Thank you again.

Comment: @marchochesi   Thank you for the help.  I am sure I will have more issues as I finish building the site, but your help was indispensable.  Thank you.

Comment: @marchochesi    I spoke too soon.  Now I have a new problem that I describe above in the new edit.  I think it is a problem of where I have located the endif; and the endwhile;

Comment: The `endwhile` should go after the (first) `foreach` closing `}`. The `endif` is right where it is. Could you post the source code on pastebin, it is long and not very readable here without indentation...

Comment: Here is the link to the pastebin post. http://pastebin.com/mv33Rtjc Thank you and sorry for my poor php formatting. I am learning that too.

Comment: 1. Is it normal that in the query the 'film_time' key is not considereded? 2. There's a unused `echo $count` (this shouldn't create problems though). 3. It seems you did not really change `asort` to `sort`

Comment: 1. I just didn't code the film_time output yet since the whole loop wasn't working.  I fixed it in the example code [pastebin.com/mv33Rtjc](pastebin.com/mv33Rtjc) .  2. I removed the unused `echo $count`  3. I changed `asort` back to `sort`.  I tried it both ways and it didn't work.  4.  I am trying to read about `foreach` arrays to figure out why the date is being over written.  If you could shed any light it would help.  You have already done so much.  Thank you.

Comment: I figured it out. -- (I think...) I put the `$times = array();`  before the `$args = array` rather than within the `if ($event_query->have_posts()) : while ($event_query->have_posts()) :  $event_query->the_post();`  This seems to work so far.  I am currently testing it with a bunch of mock events.  Now I need to get more efficient with time converting so I can output the dates and times nicely.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're right. The `$times = array();` goes before the `while` loop, otherwise it is reset at every post. Sorry for not have noticed it. I'm glad you succedeed anyway.